# Why aren't standard escape sequences like \a ,\v working?Why ' works without \,and is \? standard?

Tags: c, escaping

Why aren't `\a` (beep),`\v`(vertical tab) not working in my program even though they are standard according to the links below?And why is a single quotation mark working even without using it as `\'`? And finally,is `\?` an escape character at all as that Microsoft site says,because I use the **?** symbol inside a `printf()` format string without `\` and it works fine.

To put it clearly:

- Why are `\a` and `\v` not working?
- Why single quote works without the `\` even though `\'` is an escape sequence?
- Is `\?` an escape sequence?(The link says so but **?** works without the `\`)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Comment: Inside a string literal, you don't need to escape single quotes, inside a character constant, you don't need to escape a double quote. That's because there is no danger of confusing it with the delimiter. `\v` works fine here, but not all terminals understand it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formfeed (\f) and vertical tab (\v) not working in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184548/formfeed-f-and-vertical-tab-v-not-working-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Why are `\a` and `\v` not working?

Because the console you’re using doesn’t support them. The compiler does, and produces the correct character code in the output, but the terminal emulator ignores them.

> - Why single quote works without the `\` even though `\'` is an escape sequence?

Because it’s unnecessary to escape it in strings, you only need to escape it in a `char` literal. Same for `\"` for `string` literal:

- `"'"` vs. `'\''`
- `'"'` vs. `"\""`

> - Is `\?` an escape sequence? (The link says so but `?` works without the `\`)

The link actually says something different:

> Note that … `\?` specifies a literal question mark *in cases where the character sequence would be misinterpreted as a trigraph*

It’s only there to avoid ambiguity in cases where the following characters would form a valid trigraph, such as `??=` (which is the trigraph for `#`). If you want to use this sequence in a string, you need to escape the first (or second) `?`.

Comment: Do you mean `'"'` vs. `'\"'` instead of `'"'` vs. `"\""` ?Typo?

Comment: @Thokchom No, I mean what I wrote. `"` only needs to be escaped in a string literal (obviously, because otherwise it would end the string), not in a char literal.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the escape sequences are device specific. So they don't produce the desired on effect on every device. For example, the vertical tab (`\v`) and form feed (`\f`) escape sequences do not affect screen output. But they do perform the appropriate printer operations.