# Formfeed (\f) and vertical tab (\v) not working in C

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2013

After a long time I am writing a C program. While writing the program I had to use formfeed and vertical tab. so I used \f and \v in program.

But while running the code instead of Formfeed and vertical tab I can see symbols of male and female. I don't know why it is not working.

Below is my code sample :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("I am \f SpiderCode\n");
    printf("I am \v SpiderCode\n");
    getch();
}
```

[**Note:** I am using visual studio 2013 for above code]

**Output of the above code**

[image]

Comment: You'll need [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Teletype_with_papertape_punch_and_reader.jpg/450px-Teletype_with_papertape_punch_and_reader.jpg).

Comment: @HansPassant : Ha ha. Good solution. I am going to buy this :p

Comment: Exactly the same behavior in C# too :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your code, this is an issue with the display driver for the output of the program. The console does not recognise the '\f' and '\v' codes, so it just displays the corresponding characters instead. The '\f' maps to a character with a value 12 and '\v' to 11.

In the old days, you'd have something like ANSI.SYS running which would identify special codes and update the console, such as changing the colour, moving the cursor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work when you use '\f' '\v' , because the console does not recognize them but transfer them to ANSI characters. So you can not see expected output on screen.

But it will have an influence on printer if you print them on the paper.