# \v Vertical tab character not working in C (showing male gender symbol)

Tags: c, printf, codeblocks

Does anybody know why whenever I input \v, it outputs the male gender symbol?
For example: hello world would be hello diagonal to world on the next line

If there is an explanation for this, what can I do to overcome or solve this?

Comment: Linux, Windows or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184548/formfeed-f-and-vertical-tab-v-not-working-in-c)

Comment: It smells like some of Bill Gates's "inventions", indeed.

Comment: I saw the duplicate a while back, but I don't recall it stating any solution to it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: I do not see an explanation. I only see the history.

Comment: Code page 437.  Very likely it's your default console character set if you're using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant is correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

`\v`, "vertical tab", is ASCII 11.  Which is displayed as the male gender symbol on an IBM-compatible PC or DOS prompt using IBM code page 437.

There's no  "solution".

Q: What do you *want*?

For "screen control" in text mode, I'd strongly encourage you to look at [NCurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) or equivalent.

Although I don't necessarily recommend it, some folks are perfectly happy using [ANSI Escape Codes](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797).

And of course you can always change the code page: https://itectec.com/superuser/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8/

Comment: No because I believe \v would mean that for example, take a look at what would happen to hello world in this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380538/what-is-a-vertical-tab

Comment: Your question is "Why do I see this symbol?"  The answer is "that's the way IBM code page 437 renders ASCII 11".  If your follow-on question is "How can I implement vertical tab in a DOS prompt", I gave a couple of options.  There are probably other options as well.  But you simply *CAN'T* "printf(\v)" and expect a DOS prompt configured as code page 437 to display anything different ;)  [And that's all I have to say about that](https://i.pinimg.com/550x/45/9f/ac/459facd78b9dbaf6122bdf065188fec7.jpg)

Comment: I understand now. Thank you

Comment: Great: I'm glad I could help.  Please feel free to "upvote" and/or "accept" if you found this reply useful.  And please feel free to share whatever you ultimately decide to do.