# Why is the escape sequence '\v' not working?

Tags: python, windows, escaping

From what I have read online, the escape sequence `\v` is supposed to print text on a new line, possibly indented. I have tried it for myself a couple of ways, and it printed the unrecognized character symbol every time.

```
>>> print('text here \vmore text here')
text here more text here
```

What exactly is going on here?

Edit:

I am running it on Windows, in PyCharm. I just tried it in the command line (cmd.exe and PowerShell), and got the same thing as @scr does. This is blowing my mind as well.

```
>>> print('text here \vmore text here')
text here ♂more text here
```

Comment: Hmm it seems to work on my machine, although the size of indentation seems to depend on the previous line. Maybe it depends on the terminal emulator you are using, which is out of python's boundary?

Comment: It depends on the output device — some consoles will ignore it.

Comment: I get the following result runing it on a Windows PC:`>>> print("he\vmllo")` -> `he♂mllo`.
Which is blowing my mind.

Comment: But it works fine on my ubuntu machine. So I suppose j1-lee's point is correct.
What system are you running it on OP?

Comment: @scr that's because of the Windows terminal maintaining decades-long backwards compatibility with a convenient (for a very specific set of people making command-line DOS games), but fundamentally wrong behaviour. That character is [at Unicode code point 0x2642](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2642/index.htm) (decimal 9794), but DOS [nonstandardly maps control characters to printable glyphs](https://www.aivosto.com/articles/charsets-codepages-dos.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since we know this is not a Python issue I enlarged the search and found a solution for the same issue in C:

[Formfeed (\f) and vertical tab (\v) not working in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184548/formfeed-f-and-vertical-tab-v-not-working-in-c)

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question is no solution, it just says what I already did — it depends on the output device.

Comment: @martineau nevertheless, I count it as a perfectly adequate duplicate. The **question** was why it doesn't work, and the answer is that the output device isn't one where it works. Meanwhile, neither question is about any programming language at all, but instead about the data.